# Apps are not showing up in camera and microphone in privacy settings on a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina

Tags: macbook, camera

I have tried all solutions, and I have [tried this one on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1441270/apps-dont-show-up-in-camera-and-microphone-privacy-settings-in-macbook).

Can anyone help as I cannot attend any meeting on video conferencing? The software I am attempting to use is Zoom, Skype, Google Hangouts and Facebook Messenger. None of them show camera and audio permission requests.

[image]

Comment: What software are you using for conferencing? Stuff like Zoom? From what I know you have to first launch the app for it it actually request permission to do things.

Comment: zoom, skype, hangout even facebook messenger doesnt work

Comment: "tried this one" really doesn't tell us precisely what you did, nor what the results were. We have nothing to go on.

Comment: 1.csrutil enable and reboot didnt work 2.open Terminal.app
launchctl list | grep -i com.apple.tccd
if no matches found re-enabe your user tccd using

launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.tccd.plist   didn't work also   3.applying user permissions didn't work