# Security threat after taking advice?

Tags: security, permissions, macbook, sharing

I was following some advice trying to fix some issues with my webcam and camera permissions. I followed the top comments answers but noticed some comments later speaking of potential security threats.

"
THIS IS BAD ADVICE. THIS RECURSIVELY CHANGES ALL PERMISSIONS OF ALL FILES AND DIRECTORIES IN YOUR HOME FOLDER AND POSES A SECURITY THREAT. ALSO IT IS NOT A DIRECT ANSWER TO THE QUESTION... (just to reiterate @qwerty_so, thank you) – jorijnsmit"

"Actually a bad advice. This will change the user permission to 644 for all files in your private folder. Thus is takes back that for protected files as well (like e.g. your ~/.ssh/id_rss which in turn is no longer accepted for ssh logins). Besides that it does not solve the issu. – qwerty_so "

Is there anything I can do to reverse what I've done?

[Apps don't show up in camera and microphone privacy settings in MacBook](https://superuser.com/questions/1441270/apps-dont-show-up-in-camera-and-microphone-privacy-settings-in-macbook/1462245#1462245?newreg=d8beddc1457441fb84d6c5ece9349dd7)

[THIS IS WHAT I DID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iChap.png)

Comment: What problems were you fixing, and what changes, specifically, did you make? We need this information to even begin solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do depends a bit on the status of your computer. If it is a personal computer for yourself, it should be sufficient to look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272497/what-should-my-home-folder-permissions-look-like .

You might want to re-generate your ssh keys, if there is a chance that someone else has accessed your system.

Be sure to downvote the wrong answer if you can.

Comment: Thank you! I will downvote that answer but considering I'm new here it says I won't be publicly displayed.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it. You'll get some rep. points for accepting the answer.